# Json .Net serialize flat object into a complex object (change objects structure on serialization/deserialization)

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a flat DTO like this

```
public class User
{
    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fname")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lname")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("country")]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("state")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("zip")]
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("address1")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("address2")]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
}
```

Which is by default serialized in to a 'flat' JSON:

```
{
     'email':'john@doe.net',
     'fname':'John',
     'phone':'123456789',
     'city':'New York',
     'zip':'1111',
     'lname':'Joe',
     'state':'NY',
     'address1' : 'address1'
}
```

I would like to serialize it to more structured JSON object:

```
{
     'email':'john@doe.net',
     'fname':'John',
     'phone':'123456789',
     'lname':'Joe',
     'address' : {
         'city':'New York',
         'zip':'1111',         
         'state':'NY',
         'address1' : 'address1'
      }         
}
```

Is there any way to do it without creating a custom JsonConverter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this without a custom JsonConverter, or without adpating the structure of your *flat* model by introducing a proper `Address` class.

Comment: Well, it would also be possible with a [custom contractresolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm) - but that would be even more work.